# скрыть отображение переменной в окне Разработчика браузера

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Пытаюсь разработать набор тестовых заданий в виде php или html + js на сервере без клиента. Данные для конкретных тестов храню там же в виде js-файлов (для index.html) или текстовых файлов (для index.php). Такой файл содержит объект, включающий в себя тип теста (единственный выбор, множеств. выбор, установление соответствия и т. п.), e-mail учителя, собственно вопросы и ответы на них. Проблема в том, что каким бы образом я ни передавал этот объект в index.html или в index.php для последующего сравнения с полученными ответами, значения правильных ответов всегда открыты для доступа в окне браузера "Программный код страницы" и идея объективного тестирования, естественно, пропадает сразу.
Вот фрагмент файла данных:

```
variant_object = {
variant_1:{
 name:"единственный вибор", 
 tests:{
  longBtn:{
   name:"Выберите вопрос и единственный вариант ответа",
   data:[ 
    ["1. вопрос 1:", 
        "а) вариант ответа 1;", 
        "б) вариант ответа 2;", 
        "в) вариант ответа 3;", 
        "г) вариант ответа 4."
    ], 
    ["2. вопрос 2:", 
        "а) вариант ответа 1;", 
         ....................
    ], 
   ],//end data  
   true_answer:[[2],[2]],
   },//end test content 
   radio_slider:{
    name:"Выберите вопрос и единственный вариант ответа", 
    data:[
    ["1. Вопрос 1", 
        "вариант ответа 1;", 
        ...........
    ],
    ...............
    ],//end data 
    true_answer:[[1],[2],[3],[4]],
   },//ens test_content 
  },//end tests
  teacher:{name:"*", school:"издательство «*»", e_mail:"*"}, 
  color_scheme:"brown"
},//end variant 
variant_2:{
name:"множеств. выбор",
......................
} 
};//end variant_object
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите: как мне предотвратить отображение в браузере переменных variant_object.variant_1.tests.longBtn.true_answer и т. п. В Сети потратил кучу времени, но безрезультатно.

Заранее спасибо, Вадим Калинин

Comment: пишите код на __серверной__ стороне, и тогда в исходном коде вы не увидите ничего, кроме html и js.

Comment: Вы написали, что храните объекты с тестами в файлах. Т.е. вы буквально объект записываете в файл? А потом скорее всего этот файл парсите?

Comment: *Проблема в том, что каким бы образом я ни передавал этот объект* – сто-о-оп! А почему вы вообще передаёте его клиенту? Если уж передаёте, то хотя бы неправильные ответы, чтобы отслеживать тех, кто пытается списать :Р

Comment: Спасибо за отклик. В случае с index.html js-файл с объектом variant_object внедряю в тэг html:
script_elem = document.createElement("script");
script_elem.src = путь к js-файлу относительно index.html;
script_elem.type="text/javascript";
script_elem.async = true;
$(script_elem).appendTo("html");

Comment: В случае с index.php:
<?php
 $variantData =  путь к файлу variants.dat относительно index.php; 
 $script = file_get_contents($variantData);
?>;
var variants_object = <?php echo $script ?>;

К сожалению, в обоих случаях правильные ответы можно увидеть в окне Разработка браузера.

Comment: Эдуард, на стороне клиента нет ни одного файла. Доступ к тестам - из браузера по распространяемой ссылке на index.html c параметрами. Конечно, если я правильно понял Ваше предложение.

Answer (score 0):

Три недели поисков решения привели к следующему:

```
1. В окне браузера "программный код страницы" переменные php не видны в принципе (кроме случая echo, конечно).
2. На сервер выкладываю файл данных в читабельном виде.
3. Читаю данные в переменную php: $script = file_get_contents(<относительный путь к файлу данных>) и шифрую их:
   $out_str = "";
   $offset = 0;
   while ($offset >= 0) $out_str.= ordutf8($script, $offset) . "!" (функцию ordutf8 нашел в свободном доступе в Сети (http://php5.kiev.ua/php7/function.ord.html);
4. Готовлю переменную php, содержащую в текстовом виде js-функции s_ и D_ для декодирования:
   $script_en = 'function s_(s,c){return s.charAt(c)}\nfunction D_(){var temp=\"\",i, c=0, out=\"\"; var str=\"' . $out_str . '\"; l=str.length; while(c<=str.length-1){while(s_(str,c)!=\"!\")temp=temp+s_(str,c++); c++; out=out+String.fromCharCode(temp); temp=\"\"}; return out}' (этот алгоритм также нашел в свободном доступе в Сети и немного подправил под свою задачу (https://htmlweb.ru/java/example/cripter2.php));
5. В тэг body добавляю следующий код:
<body>
<script>
    script_elem = document.createElement("script");
    script_elem.innerText = '<?php echo $script_en ?>';
    script_elem.type="text/javascript";
    script_elem.async = true;
    $(script_elem).appendTo("html");

    variants_object = eval("("+D_()+")");
</script>   
</body>
Приведенный выше код размещается в файле index.php. В результате в пресловутом окне браузера будут видны значение переменной script_elem.innerText и код функций s_ и D_, добавленный в тэг html, содержащие исключительно закодированную информацию, а переменная variants_object по-прежнему равна eval("("+D_()+")"), т.е. тоже "не выдает" правильных ответов.
```

Допускаю, что найденное мною решение не самое удачное; во всяком случае, для неискушенного пользователя такой защиты хватит.
Еще раз спасибо всем откликнувшимся.